# Encryption algorithm selection in IPsec Phase 2

Tags: encryption, ipsec

My question is, in which payload (transform or proposal) does the initiator specify the encryption algorithm to be used in Phase 2. Let us assume that PFS is turned off in this case for simplicity of explanation.

I understand that for Phase 1, the encryption algorithm is specified in the transform payload and that the encryption mechanism used in Phase 1 and Phase 2 can be different.

I spent some time trying to find this, but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanisms differ for IKEv1 and IKEv2 and whether the initial Phase 2 (CHILD_SA) is created or one is created/rekeyed later.

With **IKEv1/ISAKMP** every IPsec SA is created with a Quick Mode exchange, which contains the SA, Proposal and Transform payloads used to negotiate the algorithms (see [RFC 2408, section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2408#section-4.2)). These algorithms don't have to be the same as those used for the ISAKMP SA. PRF is enabled by negotiating a DH group and establishing a shared secret with a DH exchange. Thus, already the first Phase 2 SA can negotiate key material independent of the Phase 1 SA.

With **IKEv2** an initial CHILD_SA is created already with the IKE_AUTH exchange. The algorithms are negotiated with [SA payloads](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-3.3) that contain proposal and transform substructures (not full payloads). As with IKEv1 the algorithms negotiated don't have to be the same as those for the IKE_SA. However, since the key material for this initial SA is derived from the IKE keys, negotiated with a DH exchange during the IKE_SA_INIT exchange, there will never be a DH group negotiated for this SA (see [RFC 7296, end of section 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-1.2)). To establish additional CHILD_SAs or to rekey existing ones CREATE_CHILD_SA exchanges are used. The payload used to transport the proposals/algorithms is the same SA payload used during the initial exchanges. In these exchanges a DH group may be negotiated and a DH exchange can be used to create key material that is independent of the IKE keys.